# field<t> invalid cast

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm having problems when using linq on a datatable.asenumerable().
This throws InvalidCastException.

```
DateTime date=r.Field<DateTime>("date");
```

This works fine.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(r.Field<string>("date"));
```

What am I missing?

Regards Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect it to work? The following code doesn't compile:

```
DateTime dt1 = (DateTime)"2004-01-01";
```

Whereas this does:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("2004-01-01");
```

As in, you can't just cast a string to a DateTime, so if your value is a string, you need to explicitly convert it.

Comment: When you put it like that it's quite obvious.
Lack of experience and working brain I guess.
Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your "date" column is of type DateTime?

This test code works as expected:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("date", typeof(DateTime)));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["date"] = DateTime.Now.AddDays(i);
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        foreach (var r in dt.AsEnumerable())
        {
            DateTime d = r.Field<DateTime>("date"); // no problems here!

            Console.Write(d.ToLongDateString());
        }
```

Comment: No the column is a string, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Cast works between related types. `string` and `date` don't belong to same hierarchy & hence no direct translation is possible.

You can use cast, when you are sure that the types are related and conversion is possible.

`Parse` is different than cast.
i.e you are telling the runtime to see if it can be parsed to make a date out of it (per your example).